# Data Pager Postback causes value lose

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net. Here is the scenario. I am trying to build a Search functionality. If I enter the value in search box i.e. "Test" and click search icon SQL Server returns results. I have limited datapage size = "1". When I click on next page it refreshes the page and my search box looses the value I entered in this case "Test". If no value is passed SQL Server returns a default result so everytime I navigate through pages it works only for first page each click after that returns me default value. I bind list view on PreRender of datapage. Here are the code snippets.

```
    protected void search_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mydatapager_PreRender(sender, e);
    }
    protected void mydatapager_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string var_search_firstname = globalsearchinput.Value.ToString();
        string var_search_city = citysearchinput.Value.ToString();
        string var_search_state = statesearchinput.Value.ToString();
        bool isadvancedsearch = false;
        //Determine whether it's advanced search or not.
        string MethodCaller = "";

        //MethodCaller = ((HtmlButton)sender).ID;

        //if (MethodCaller == "search")
        //{
        //    isadvancedsearch = false;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    isadvancedsearch = true;
        //}

        Utility utl = new Utility();

        friendrequestsentnotificationpanel.Visible = false;

        listview1.DataSource = utl.SearchProfile(var_search_firstname, var_search_city, var_search_state, isadvancedsearch);
        listview1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ispostback==false` condition in preRender. It helps to retain the serch string